# Approximate Beta density function to Gaussian density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, beta-function, gaussian

Any coefficient, $\beta_0 \in [\beta_L, \beta_U]$ is modeled in the Beta distribution and its pdf is given by

$$p(\beta_0) = \frac{\Gamma(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}{(\beta_U-\beta_L)\Gamma(\lambda_1)\Gamma(\lambda_2)}(\frac{\beta_0-\beta_L}{\beta_U-\beta_L})^{\lambda_1-1}(1-\frac{\beta_0-\beta_L}{\beta_U-\beta_L})^{\lambda_2-1},$$

where $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ are shape parameters and symbol $\Gamma$ represents the Gamma function. 
The following parameters are used: $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 1.1$, the lower limit $\beta_L = 10,000$, and the upper limit $\beta_U = 63,000$. Probability density of $\beta_0$ is shown below. [[image: Probability density of <span class=]$\beta_0$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQe6s.jpg)

Our main concern here is to approximate $p(\beta_0)$ by a Gaussian density. Any suggestion will be great help to me.

Comment: For later readers of this post, the following link can be helpful https://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/BetaNormal.pdf